# Cloning a div with multiple input is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

By default multiple input are appended to the `#captureAvail_more` below like this:

```
$(function()
{
$("#captureAvail_more").append("<input type='text' name='avail[]' value='Sun-1'>");
$("#captureAvail_more").append("<input type='text' name='avail[]' value='Sun-2'>");
$("#captureAvail_more").append("<input type='text' name='avail[]' value='Sun-3'>");

$("#captureAvail_more").append("<input type='text' name='avail[]' value='Sat-1'>");
$("#captureAvail_more").append("<input type='text' name='avail[]' value='Sat-2'>");
$("#captureAvail_more").append("<input type='text' name='avail[]' value='Sat-3'>");

}
);
```

Above will append inputs like this,

```
<section id="more-popup" class="mfp-hide white-popup">
    //append `input[type=text]` here
    <div id="captureAvail_more" class="clone_more">
    <input type='text' name='avail[]' value='Sun-1'>
    <input type='text' name='avail[]' value='Sun-2'>
    <input type='text' name='avail[]' value='Sun-3'>

    <input type='text' name='avail[]' value='Sat-1'>
    <input type='text' name='avail[]' value='Sat-2'>
    <input type='text' name='avail[]' value='Sat-3'>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="OK" id="ok" onclick="cloneAvail()"/>
</section>
```

When the ok button is clicked, I need to clone all the `input[type=text]` of this class (`'clone_more'`) with their values into `div#captureAvail2`, but its not cloning at all.  Where am I going wrong here. Below is my code for cloning.

//HTML inputs from .clone_more need to be appended here

```
 <div id="captureAvail2">
    </div>
```

Function to clone

```
function cloneAvail()
{
    alert("hi");
    $(".clone_more input[type=text]").clone(true, true).append("#captureAvail2");
}
```

Comment: appendTo http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Comment: @gp., what a silly mistake I made! Thanks bro